# Facebook Fanpage increased to 520

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

I created a fanpage and integrated a app with width 520px. Everything works fine but the context is 5px to 10px shifts to the right and so on there is a scrollbar shown at the end of page. How can I solve this.

I know scrollbars can be hidden with `overflow:hidden` and inside tag `<body scroll=no>` but this doesn´t solve the shift to the right.

[image]

Comment: Can you attach an image to explain what a «shift to the right» is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that facebook fanpages tabs have a html - padding with 8px!!!! to solve this I set in css: `<body style="position:relative;left:-8px;">`

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow` method :

Please read the [Facebook JS SDK Documentation of the FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow method](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow/).  In that link is an explanation on how to use facebooks auto size functions to fix these sorts of problems.

Comment: Good for you my friend! You should post an answer to yourself too.  After a little while you'll be able to accept your own answer.